# 125 MHz parallel bus in a double 2.54mm header

Tags: fpga, connector, ethernet, differential, header

I have a BeMicro CV low cost dev board from Altera. It features a Cyclone V.

[FYI: Schematics and gerber here](http://parts.arrow.com/fr/reference-design/5C58DD61B82A0C8D7E6E301154EEC5BA)

They routed impedance controlled differential lines to some dual 2.54mm standard headers.

See the at the top of the picture below:
[image]

It seems that they cared about the controlled impedance, and also the line lengths.

I would like to connect a 1000Mbit PHY with GMII interface (parallel 125MHz clock).

Can I plug a daughter board to this one and convey the 125MHz signals using a simple 2.45mm header?

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is, why would the designer expend the effort to route the signals, particularly all the fiddling with matched lengths and impedance control, if they didn't expect it to work?  The short answer is, it should work perfectly well - especially if you take the same kind of care with your daughter board.

Comment: I see your point. But I hove not idea of the max speed of that connector. They may have routed the board that way having 30MHz signals in mind. Who knows? This is not documented. And because this is logic signalling. The frequency content of the signal is defined by the rise time that may end up to 500MHz+ of required bandwidth. But even at those frequencies, the length of the connector is small regarding lambda max (no ribbon cables). Thus I don't know what to think.

Comment: Given that they're differential traces, and given the likely LVDS signalling capabilities of the FPGA, I'd expect them to work perfectly well up to several hundred MHz if not a GHz or so.  Also, you could always ask the vendor of the board.

Comment: Try to get the RLC model of the connector from tyco or samtec. You can simulate the whole path. suggestion is altera very good company without proper thought they will not include these headers in to the board and Differential traces will be more tolerant to SI compared to Single ended signals.

Comment: Try to get the RLC model of the connector from tyco or samtec. You can simulate the whole path. suggestion is altera very good company without proper thought they will not include these headers in to the board and Differential traces will be more tolerant to SI compared to Single ended signals.I have just downloaded Single line Model of AMPMODU type connector and see R=12m,L=2.5n,C=0.6p--> These values are very less. They will not cause much loading. Tpd is around 39ps which is also very less.

Comment: @user19579 Other answer are good too but your comment is the most useful to me, I think. You should convert it to an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Blup1980: It's ok, i can't frame proper answers. can give comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should work. These connectors seem to have relatively low capacitance.

If you are really worry about this - you may try to pass 125MHz or even faster signal from lab generator and see what is going on oscilloscope.

These connectors were used for ATA hard disks, and they were working with pretty long ribbon wire with bus speed up to 33MHz, so without that ribbon cable there should be no problem with 125MHz (or 125MHz differential signal).

[image: ata bus frequency]

Source:

Upgrading and Repairing PCs
Scott Mueller

http://books.google.com/books?id=E1p2FDL7P5QC

Answer (score 1):

Although the lines look like matched pairs, they are not (by the look of it) matched between themsleves, so the delays on each of your databits is likely to be different.  This will eat into the margin that your interface has (unless you are making a custom daughterboard, in which case you can compensate for the differences in delay on by making your traces shorter where they connect to long traces on the main board.

Having said that, the differences are likely to be very small, and at 125MHz single-data rate (which is what GMII is), I imagine you'd be OK.

More of an issue might be if there are enough ground connections to enable the signals to make it across cleanly.  If there are very few ground connections, you will get "ground-bounce", which in the worst case makes your clock look like it has two edges where there should be one!